# Python: Extract a paragraph between two section numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expression and extract a paragraph between two section numbers. Any comments are highly appreciated!

A little bit information of what I want to achieve. I want to extract the Confidentiality section out of a loan contract. Hence, my paragraph will start with the section number and the word "Confidentiality". It will stop at the next section number.

This is my code:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
confi=  re.findall(r'\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\s*Confidentiality\.\s*(.*?)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}',f.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

This is the example paragraph:

> 13.18 Confidentiality. In the event that any of the Borrowers provides to the Agent, the Floor Plan Agent or any Lender, (…) obligation of confidence under this Section**13.18** shall not apply to such portions of the information (…) participants and prospective assignees and participants who agree to be bound by the terms of this Section13.18, (…) such information as is imposed upon it hereunder.
>   13.19 Waiver of jury trial.

However, the code does not capture the paragraph between 13.18 and 13.19, but right at "Section 13.18" in the middle of the paragraph. The complication is that the section number does not always remain 13.18, but varies with different text files. I appreciate your comment!

Comment: You might consider adding `\s[A-Z]` at the end so that your regular expression stops only if the number has a space and an upper case letter after it. Although I’m not sure if this will generalize to all of your cases, it might be a start since it looks like each section starts with something of the form XX.XX A where X is a number and A is a capital letter.

Comment: Try `r'(?ms)^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\s*Confidentiality\.\s*(.*?)(?=^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\s|\Z)'`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ex1CN9/1).